# how to publish the necessary information from a big JSON file that includes a lot of arrays inside it

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, reactjs, react-redux

I m trying to publish some information that I get from `'http://localhost:3001/api'`
this comes in the following format:
[image]

I need the information inside: `Agents, Itinerarie, Legs, Segments`

here is my action:

```
export function fetchLocals() { 
    return (dispatch) => { 

        dispatch({type: GET_LOCATIONS_START}); 
        axios.get('http://localhost:3001/api') 
        .then(function(response) { 
            dispatch({type: GET_DATA_AGENTS, payload: response.data.Agents}); 
            dispatch({type: GET_DATA_ITI, payload: response.data.Itinerarie}); 
            dispatch({type: GET_DATA_LEGS, payload: response.data.Legs}); 
            dispatch({type: GET_DATA_SEGMENTS, payload: response.data.Segments});
        })
        .catch(function (error) { 
            dispatch({type: GET_LOCATIONS_ERROR, payload: error}); 
        });
```

here is my reducer:

```
export default (state = [], action) => {
    const payload = action.payload
  
    switch (action.type) {       
        case GET_DATA_AGENTS: 
        state.agents = payload 
        return state; 
        //return [ payload.agents]

        case GET_DATA_ITI: 
        state.iti = payload 
        return state;
        //return [ payload.iti ]

        case GET_DATA_LEGS: 
        state.legs = payload 
        return state;
        //return [ payload.legs ]

        case GET_DATA_SEGMENTS: 
        state.segments = payload 
        return state;
        //case GET_DATA_SEGMENTS: [payload.segments]
    }
    return state;
}
```

and my container:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import moment from 'moment';

class SkyScannerList extends Component {

    renderFlights(flightData){
        console.log("I AM HERE NOW"); 
        console.log(flightData); 
        <div>Loading.....</div>
        //const result = flightData.data.length;     
        //console.log(flightData);  
    } 

    render(){
        return (
            <table className="table table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>Airline</th>
                        <th>Flight Number</th>
                        <th>From</th>
                        <th>To</th>
                        <th>Departure</th>
                        <th>Arrival</th>
                        <th>Cost</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                {
                    this.props.skyScanner.map(this.renderFlights)
                }
            </table>
        );
    }

}

const mapStateToProps=({ skyScanner })=>{
    return { skyScanner };
};
/*
function mapStateToProps(skyScanner){
    return{
        Agents: state.Agents,
        Itinerarie: state.Itinerarie,
        Legs: state.Legs,
        Segments: state,Segments
    };
}
*/
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SkyScannerList);
```

when I run my application, I can see under console:

> I AM HERE NOW
>
> undefined

which means that `flightData` is undefined, it doesnt event show e `Loading...`. I am trying to publish some information from those 4 arrays at my container and I think my reducers are not working correctly. can someone help me out here and point me to my mistakes?

How can I  publish all ids inside `Agents, Legs, Segments` and InboundLegId and OutboundLegId from `Itinerarie` for each available flight?

am I clear about what I want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using map() wrong way. Try this and let me know if this helps:

```
this.props.skyScanner.map((item) => this.renderFlights(item))
```

UPDATE:

Ok after our chat conversation. It seems that your reducers are wrong.

You need to return an initial_state. Here is your new reducer file:

```
const initial_state={
    agents: [],
    iti: [],
    legs: [],
    segments: [],
    places: [],
    carriers: []
};

export default (state = initial_state, action) => {
    const payload = action.payload;
    switch (action.type) {
        case GET_DATA_AGENTS:
            return({
                ...state,
                agents: payload.Agents,
                iti: payload.Itineraries,
                legs: payload.Legs,
                segments: payload.Segments,
                places: payload.Places,
                carriers: payload.Carriers
            });
            break;
        default: return state;
    }
}
```

You don't need to dispatch for each item in data. Just change the action to this.

```
dispatch({type: GET_DATA_AGENTS, payload: response.data});
```

you also need to change your `mapStateToProps` function:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        data: state.skyScanner
    }
}
```

now just pass to your function

```
this.renderFlights(this.props.data);
```

Comment: Well it is because this.props.skyScanner is empty

Comment: can we dicuss this in chat>

Comment: try putting condolr.log(this.props.skyScanner) right after declaring your render() { and show me what you get?

Comment: sure go ahead :)

Comment: I dont know how to start a chat converstaion here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164577/discussion-between-khun-and-s-n).